# Crontab to get list of scripts at particular intervals

Tags: python, cron

How do we get a list of scripts running in crontab between particular time say 4:00PM to 8:00PM using python crontab 
I am getting list of all the jobs running in crontab by that user but not able to get at that particular time.

tried this way:

getting list of all scripts.

```
from crontab import CronTab
import datetime
import croniter

cron = CronTab("user")

for j in cron:
   print j
```

tried for between  that particular timings:

```
from crontab import CronTab
import datetime
import croniter

cron = CronTab("pfmuser")

for j in cron:
    hour = int(j.split()[1])
    minutes = int(j.split()[0])
    if hour >= 16 and hour <= 20:
        print('fond a job running between 16 and 20')
```

got error:AttributeError: 'CronItem' object has no attribute 'split'

error is done but

```
***but now i have:
1) 10 0 * * 5
2)  0 3 1 * *
3)  0 0 * * *
4)  0 1 * * *
5)  0 10 * * * 

now if have some problem and the cron scripts didnt run then if i am running for 0-10th hour then i need only 

3)  0 0 * * *
4)  0 1 * * *
5)  0 10 * * *  
these scripts only should run 

1) 10 0 * * 5  (only friday)
2)  0 3 1 * * (only 1st month)
these should not run 

how to  keep  this may be can i use datetime and get that particular details later compare with the cron info.How do i go***
```

edited script with the suggestions given below:

```
from crontab import CronTab
import datetime
from croniter import croniter as ci

cron = CronTab("pfmuser")

for cronitem in cron:

    cronitemstr = str(cronitem)
    hour = cronitemstr.split()[1]
    minutes = cronitemstr.split()[0]
    minutesint = None
    hourint = None
    try:
        hourint = int(hour)
        minutesint = int(minutes)
    except ValueError as e:
        print e.message
    if hourint >= 16 and hourint <= 20:
        cronitemstr = cronitemstr[:cronitemstr.index(cronitemstr.split()[5])]

        min=cronitemstr.split()[0]
        dom=cronitemstr.split()[2]
        mon=cronitemstr.split()[3]
        dow=cronitemstr.split()[4]
       date_time=datetime.datetime.now()
        try:
           if(min=='*' and dom=='*' and mon=='*' and dow=='*' ):
                print cronitemstr
                print cronitem
           else:
                print "none"
        except Exception as e:
            print "e"
```

need to include more conditions in if clause as we need to include even

- 16 * * 3 : dis is as per today thursday at 16 th hr it need to work so this script also should be displayed
- 16 * * 1-5 : means for mon,tues,wed,thur,fri it should run so this also should be displayed.
- 16 * 10 * : means every day in 10th month 16th hr it need to execute..so this also should display 
  like that we need to check many conditions. according to me i think that i need to consider todays date like datetime.date.today() from that need to compare withh cron expression.
  prsently  * 16 * * * means all the scripts in 16th hr of min,day,month.this would be only one instancce need to consider all those which need to be included

Comment: cron.find_time("* * * * *") can dis command help me

Answer (score 1):

The cronitem object is not a string and therefore does not have the attribute split. You can cast it to a str before you try to split. For example:

```
from crontab import CronTab
import datetime
from croniter import croniter as ci

cron = CronTab("pfmuser")



for cronitem in cron:

    cronitemstr = str(cronitem)
    hour = cronitemstr.split()[1]
    minutes = cronitemstr.split()[0]
    minutesint = None
    hourint = None
    try:
        hourint = int(hour)
        minutesint = int(minutes)
    except ValueError as e:
        print e.message

    print hourint
    print minutesint
    if hourint >= 16 and minutesint <= 20:
        print('found a job running between 16 and 20')

        cronitemstr = cronitemstr[:cronitemstr.index(cronitemstr.split()[5])]
        iter = ci(cronitemstr)
        next_run = iter.get_next()
        last_run = iter.get_prev()
        next_run_datetime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(next_run)
        last_run_datetime= datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(last_run)
        print 'the next run is at {}'.format(next_run_datetime)
        print 'the last run was at {}'.format(last_run_datetime)
```

Comment: Thanks done with the error by converting tp int now need for specifications kindly check the edit

Comment: You can easily parse the cron string using croniter. This will tell you when the next run should be. You could also find out when previous runs should have occurred. I have edited the code to show this.

Comment: Let me know if this answers it for you.